# Relationship between subharmonic functions and Laplacian

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations

> Show that if $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ is subharmonic then $\Delta u\geq 0$ in $\Omega$.

---

Here is my proposed solution. I read [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186243/subharmonic-function-equivalent-non-negative-laplacian) but couldn't follow every step (I am still relatively new to PDE). Please let me know if my proposed solution is correct or if I made a major mistake.

---

First, let's define $u\in C^2(\Omega)$ as subharmonic if it satisfies

$$u(x_0)\leq \frac{1}{\omega_n r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r(x_0)}u(y)dA_{\partial B_r(x_0)}(y)$$

for all $x_0\in\Omega$ where $r\geq 0$ and $\overline{B_r(x_0)}\subset\Omega$.

We will argue by contradiction. Assume that there is an $x_0\in\Omega$ such that $\Delta u(x_0)<0$. For concreteness, assume that $\Delta u(x_0)=-\delta<0$.

As $u\in C^2(\Omega)$, there exists a $r_{\delta} < \mathrm{dist}(x_0,\partial\Omega)$ such that

$$|\Delta u(x_0)- \Delta u(y)| < \frac{\delta}{2}$$

for all $y$ where $|x_0-y|<r_{\delta}$. In particular, $\Delta u(y)< -\delta/2$ in $B_{r_\delta}(x_0)$.

So, let's define $\Psi(r)$ according to

$$\Psi(r)=\frac{1}{\omega_n r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r(x_0)}u(y)dA_{\partial B_r(x_0)}(y)$$

Then, for $r<r_\delta$, we have that

$$\Psi'(r)=\frac{1}{\omega_n} \int_{B_1(0)} \Delta u(rz + x_0)dz < -\frac{1}{\omega_n} \int_{B_1(0)} r^2\frac{\delta}{2}dz < 0$$

As $u\in C^2(\Omega)$, we have that $\lim_{r\to 0^+}\Psi(r)=u(x_0)$. Thus, by the above equation, we see that $\Psi(r)<u(x_0)$ for $r\in(0,r_{\delta})$. This is a direct contradiction to the subharmonic property

$$u(x_0)\leq \frac{1}{\omega_n r^{n-1}}\int_{\partial B_r(x_0)}u(y)dA_{\partial B_r(x_0)}(y)$$

for all $x_0\in\Omega$ where $r\geq 0$ and $\overline{B_r(x_0)}\subset\Omega$.

Comment: It seems ok to me, in the way that you have used the same technique as Evans uses to prove the MVP. You take the derivative of the MVP integral to make appear the Laplacian, then this should reach the desired contradiction. You can work in the same way backwards to prove the iff.

Comment: I don't mean the iff of the original question, but reversing the definition of what subharmonic means. Subharmonicity can be defined in the same way as what you are asked to prove, and then you have to prove what holds for the MVP.

Comment: I see, the crucial step at the end is the conclusion that $\Psi(r)<u(x_0)$ for $r\in(0,r_{\delta})$. I'm still curious if there is a better way of writing this, as the above equation is the first derivative and it isn't immediately clear that this is true without writing the definitions.